# How do you trigger one to many relationship between (many to many) table and a normal table?

Tags: entity-relationship, rdbms

I am trying to make one to many relationship between Contacts table and DepartmentTitle table.

I was thinking of introducing surrogate key on DepartmentTitle table so that I can reference this DepartmentTitle to Contacts table to trigger one to many relationship between these two tables. But I don't want to register same combination of the composite keys in the DepartmentTitle and that has prevented me from introducing the surrogate key to the table. I want the combination of composite keys in DepartmentTitle table to be unique.

To remedy the situation, I thought of implementing below ER diagram, where departmentTitleID would be unique and is used as reference id to the table (but is not primary key). Would this work? If not, what would be the solution?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to introduce a surrogate key, use it as your primary key. However, I would rather have Department_ID and Title_ID as separate columns in Contacts, since that allows Contacts to be joined directly to Department and/or Title as needed, without always needing to join DepartmentTitle. You can still have a composite foreign key constraint from the two columns in Contacts to the same in DepartmentTitle.